# postgresql - remote database : phppgadmin not able to login, where python psycopg2 is able to connect and fetch data

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

I am trying to access a remote database of postgresql. I am working in a python project

I am able to access a table using psycopg2

```
import psycopg2
server_host = 'xx.x.xx.xx'
server_dbname = 'dbname'
server_username = 'username'
server_password = 'password'
connection_for_data_and_variables = psycopg2.connect(host=server_host, database=server_dbname, user=server_username, password=server_password)

cursor = connection_for_data_and_variables.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT r1, r2 FROM tablename WHERE t1=%s ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;', ("Test", ))
a = cursor.fetchone()
```

I have the following in the `/usr/share/webapps/phppgadmin/conf/config.inc.php` of phpmyadmin

```
    // Example for a second server (PostgreSQL for Windows)
    $conf['servers'][1]['desc'] = 'Test Server';
    $conf['servers'][1]['host'] = 'xx.x.xx.xx';
    $conf['servers'][1]['port'] = 5432;
    //$conf['servers'][1]['sslmode'] = '';
    $conf['servers'][1]['defaultdb'] = 'template1';
    $conf['servers'][1]['pg_dump_path'] = '';
    $conf['servers'][1]['pg_dumpall_path'] = '';
```

When i try to login i get:

[image]

Also apache configuration:

`/etc/httpd/conf/extra/phppgadmin.conf`

```
Alias /phppgadmin "/usr/share/webapps/phppgadmin"
<Directory "/usr/share/webapps/phppgadmin">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymlinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Are you connecting from same machine with Python and PHP code? Have you looked at Postgres log for error information?

Comment: I dont have access to the remote postgresql database. I am running the php and python code on same maching

Comment: So is the database name for Test Server in phpPgAdmin the same as in the Python code? Do you have `psql` on this machine to test with?

Comment: there is no way to specify database for phppgadmin

Comment: Yes there is change the name in the conf file: `$conf['servers'][1]['defaultdb'] = 'template1';`. I would change the name to 'postgres' for now and see if that works. Can uou connect using `psql`?

Comment: i already added that

Comment: Great it worked, I chaged to the dbname i am accessin and it worked, thank you verymuch